# A non null OffsetDateTime attribute causes an error when using #temporal.format in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

## Trouble with temporal date formatting

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method format

However the object in question emits properly if not formatted.

If someone would be so kind as to tell me how I am supposed to use #temporal.format I would greatly appreciate it.

### pom.xml fragment

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

### ThymeleafComposite.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
</style>
<body>
    now is <p th:text="${bean.getNow()}">
</body>
</html>
```

### ThymeleafCompositeErr.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
</style>
<body>
    now is <p th:text="${bean.getNow()}">
    <!--        th:text="${#temporals.format(notice.date,'dd-MM-yyyy')} -->
    today is <p th:text="${#temporals.format(bean.getNow(), 'dd-MM-yyyy')}">
    time is <p th:text="${#temporals.format(bean.getNow(), 'HH:mm')}">
</body>
</html>
```

### Bean

```
package org.javautil.thymeleaf;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
public class ThymleafCompositeBean {

    private OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now();
    public OffsetDateTime getNow() {
        return now;
    }

    public void setNow(OffsetDateTime now) {
        this.now = now;
    }
}
```

### Code

```
package org.wtf.thymeleaf;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.javautil.json.GsonUtils;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;


public class ThymeleafBeanTest {
    //private   Context context = new Context();

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    private ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

    public ThymeleafBeanTest() throws IOException {
        resolver.setPrefix("/thymeleaf/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML); // HTML5 option was deprecated in 3.0.0
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
    }


    public String process(Context context,String model) {
        String retval = templateEngine.process(model,context);
        return retval;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ThymleafCompositeBean bean = new ThymleafCompositeBean();
        ThymeleafBeanTest th = new ThymeleafBeanTest();
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("bean",bean);
        System.out.println(th.process(context,"ThymeleafCompositeBean"));
        System.out.println(th.process(context,"ThymeleafCompositeBeanError"));
    }
}
```

### Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
</style>
<body>
    now is <p>2022-03-07T04:52:11.262359-05:00</body>
</html>
ERROR  TemplateEngine:process - [THYMELEAF][main] Exception processing template "ThymeleafCompositeBeanError": Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "#temporal.format(bean.getNow(), 'dd-MM-yyyy')" (template: "ThymeleafCompositeBeanError" - line 10, col 14)
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "#temporal.format(bean.getNow(), 'dd-MM-yyyy')" (template: "ThymeleafCompositeBeanError" - line 10, col 14)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:191)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048)
    at org.javautil.thymeleaf.ThymeleafBeanTest.process(ThymeleafBeanTest.java:32)
    at org.javautil.thymeleaf.ThymeleafBeanTest.main(ThymeleafBeanTest.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method format
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1613)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:467)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:431)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.executeExpression(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:316)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:170)
    ... 18 more
Exception in thread "main" org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "#temporal.format(bean.getNow(), 'dd-MM-yyyy')" (template: "ThymeleafCompositeBeanError" - line 10, col 14)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:191)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048)
    at org.javautil.thymeleaf.ThymeleafBeanTest.process(ThymeleafBeanTest.java:32)
    at org.javautil.thymeleaf.ThymeleafBeanTest.main(ThymeleafBeanTest.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method format
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1613)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:467)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:431)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.executeExpression(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:316)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:170)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Are you configuring your template engine to work with Java8Time API (with Java8TimeDialect). Please take a look at the following link, especially chapter 3. https://baeldung.com/dates-in-thymeleaf

Comment: See the top listing, the pom.xml fragment.